# Firebase throws java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException when trying to store an android.location.Address to Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

With Firebase Database in Android, I'm getting the `RuntimeException` when trying to setValue() using an subclass (ExtAddress) of class android.location.Address. While checking out the Address source code [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/location/java/android/location/Address.java), I don't know what are the conflicts between the Address class with how Firebase handles setValue().

Here is my ExtAddress class definition:

```
public class ExtAddress extends android.location.Address {
     public ExtAddress(){ // req. no arg constructor for fb 
          super(Locale.getDefault());
     }
}
```

This is my error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

Version: I'm using the Firebase Database 11.8.0 with FirebaseUi '3.2.1'.